# La Marseillaise : les /r/, couplets usuels ?

Tags: prononciation, paroles-de-chanson, france, conventions

En 1989, [*Mireille Mathieu*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mireille_Mathieu) interprète, de manière particulièrement émouvante, [*La Marseillaise*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Marseillaise)<sup>1</sup> au *Champ-de-Mars* ([noir et blanc « légendaire](https://youtu.be/SIxOl1EraXA)», ou [audio uniquement](https://youtu.be/R3IvXo0W1YI)); on chante, hormis le **premier** couplet et le refrain, les couplets **5** et **6**. J'ai aussi consulté [quelques enregistrements](http://gallicalabs.bnf.fr/services/engine/search/sru?operation=searchRetrieve&version=1.2&query=%28gallica%20all%20%22marseillaise%22%29%20and%20dc.type%20all%20%22sonore%22) plus traditionnels; souvent **6**, parfois **3** ou **4**. Dans toutes les interprétations écoutées, incluant celle de 1989, les **/r/** des mots du refrain et des couplets me *semblent* *roulés* (mon oreille).

[image]

<sup>[*Fédération générale des Français au Champ de Mars, le 14 juillet 1790*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%AAte_de_la_F%C3%A9d%C3%A9ration); [estampe]. (Dessiné par C. Monet, Peintre du Roi ; gravé par Helman, de l'Académie des Arts de Lille en Flandre ; [eau-forte de A.J. Duclos], [détails sur *bnF-Gallica*](http://gallicalabs.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/btv1b69476006/f1.item.zoom))</sup>

---

1. Dans l'interprétation de *Madame Mathieu*, comment le phonème
   [/r/](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phon%C3%A8me_/r/_en_fran%C3%A7ais) est-il réalisé ? Est-ce une prononciation habituelle ou un emploi particulier quand on interprète l'hymne national ?
2. Usuellement, quand on chante *La Marseillaise* aujourd'hui, quel(s)
   couplets chante-t-on ? Y a-t-il une convention à ce sujet ? ([couplets](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Marseillaise#Paroles))

---

<sub>1. J'ai lu des extraits des [débats](http://gallicalabs.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k65713547/f5.item.r=%22Il%20y%20a%20eu%20ensuite,%20au%2014%20juillet%22.zoom) au sénat en 1880 sur l'instauration du *14 juillet* comme [*fête nationale de la France*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%AAte_nationale_fran%C3%A7aise). Puis, sur *Wikipédia*, que [*La Marseillaise*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Marseillaise), composée en 1792 par *Claude Joseph Rouget dit de Lisle* pour les forces françaises dans le contexte de la guerre avec l'Autriche, est « *un chant patriotique de la Révolution française adopté par la France comme hymne national* » en 26 messidor an III (14 juillet 1795), et de nouveau sous la *Troisième République* en 1879 (aujourd'hui dans l'[art. 2](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_2_de_la_Constitution_de_la_Cinqui%C3%A8me_R%C3%A9publique_fran%C3%A7aise) de la Constitution de la *Cinquième République*). On mentionne que l’œuvre comporte jusqu'à *15 couplets*.</sub>

Comment: La réponse au 1. est assez simple : Mireille Mathieu est connue pour sa tendance à rouler les "r", cela est donc propre à sa prononciation. Plus tôt, Edith Piaf était elle aussi réputée pour cela.

Comment: Même question? https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/7575/trilled-rolled-rs

Comment: @Bartdude Ni l’une ni l’autre ne roulent les r : elles les [grasseyent](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonème_/r/_en_français).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1/ Le r de Mireille Mathieu est un /R/ [r roulé uvulaire voisé](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consonne_roul%C3%A9e_uvulaire_vois%C3%A9e) qui a quasiment disparu du français contemporain. Cette prononciation n'est en rien liée à l'interprétation de l'hymne national. Outre Edith Piaf déjà citée, on la retrouve chez des chanteurs comme Jacques Brel et Georges Brassens et dans les enregistrements de beaucoup d'hommes politiques plutôt nés à la fin du XIXème siècle, le plus notoire étant Charles de Gaulle.

Il ne faut pas confondre ce /R/ avec le /r/ [r roulé alvéolaire voisé](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consonne_roul%C3%A9e_alv%C3%A9olaire_vois%C3%A9e) typique de l'espagnol, présent au Québec et en voie de disparition en Bourgogne et dans le sud-ouest de la France.

2/ Comme l'a déjà dit Steven BENET, premier couplet + refrain.

Comment: Pour info, quand on parle de Mireille Mathieu, on a plus tendance à dire MiReille (en insistant sur le R comme elle a tendance à le faire) que Mathieu (qui donne l'impression que c'est un homme)

Comment: @Divulgâchâmes Ce n'est pas vraiment une question de "familliarité". Cela fait vraiment bizarre de parler de la sorte d'une personnalité publique - le fait d'être célèbre affranchit de certaines barrières et donc désigner une personnalité publique, notament un chanteur; par son prénom est plus naturel. Beaucoup de chanteur n'ont qu'un prénom pour nom de scène. Le mieux étant, si vous voulez garder une certaine distance, d'utiliser son nom complet (qui est aussi son nom de scène).

Comment: @Divulgâchâmes d'où le fait que j'ai mis ca dans les commentaires. Mais après, oui, vous pouvez bien vous exprimez comme vous voulez, il n'y a pas de soucis la-dessus. C'était un simple remarque sur ce qui a plutôt tendance à se faire et se dire, aucunement une règle. L'intérêt étant juste ici de différencier le francais courrament parlé dans la rue, du francais chatié parlé en société - où même dans ces cercles, je doute qu'ils parlent de "Mathieu"... Quand à l'administration, ils auront tendance à parler de Mme Mathieu.

Answer (score 2):

On a tendance à ne chanter que le refrain ou 1er couplet + refrain.
La plupart des français ne connaissent pas la suite je pense. Et si on devait tout chanter avant un match, on serait pas prêt de le commencer.

La Marseillaise est souvent chantée par des "vieux" chanteurs, qui ont cette tendance à rouler les *r* un peu comme le faisait Edith Piaf, ou Jacques Brel.
C'est parfaitement propre au style qu'ils veulent donner, mais absolument pas une obligation dans la façon de la chanter.

Comment: Je note "**le style** qu'ils veulent donné", que je n'arriverait même pas à décrire... De mon ressenti, cela donne un effet plus soutenu, distingué, voir de la haute société... Je ne vois pas un "paysan" marquer les "r" de cette façon... mais encore une fois, je me trompe peut-être. Ce qui est sûr c'est que très peu de personnes aujourd'hui prononcent de la sorte...